how to tidy up a table
I use LaTeX on IEEEtran with TeXLive version 2022 for writing a table as follows.

The code is as follows.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\caption{Transitions and Places of TEG in Fig.~\ref{fig:TEG_5_Steps}}

\label{tab:table_MRT_2} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} { | c | >{\centering\arraybackslash} X  | >{\centering\arraybackslash} X |}

  \hline
  \textbf{\makecell{ Variables}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Value}}   \\
  \hline
  $X^{1}$ &  $A^{\prime}_{X^{1}} \equiv \{P_{x^{1}_{[1]}}^{\prime}, P_{x^{1}_{[2]}}^{\prime\prime},P_{x^{1}_{[3]}}^{\prime}\}$ & $A^{\prime\prime}_{X^{1}} \equiv \{P_{x_{[1]}}^{\prime\prime}, P_{x_{[2]}}^{\prime}, P_{x_{[3]}}^{\prime\prime}\}$  \\
  \hline
   $X^{2}$ & $A^{\prime}_{X^{2}} \equiv \{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}^{\prime}, P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}^{\prime\prime},P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}^{\prime},P^{\prime\prime}_{x^{2}_{[4]}},P^{\prime}_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\}$ & $A^{\prime\prime}_{X^{2}} \equiv \{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}^{\prime\prime}, P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}^{\prime},P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}^{\prime\prime},P^{\prime}_{x^{2}_{[4]}},P^{\prime\prime}_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\}$  \\
   \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}



However the table looks messy as follows.

What should I do with the code?
Thank you.

It looks like you've made the table as wide as it can go with tabularx, but that using one of twos column format doesn't give you enough room.  Are you able to use both columns (\begin{table*}, I believe)?  Otherwise, what you should do with the code depends on how you want the output to change.  And I don't see a good way to squeeze that output into the room you're allowing for it.

unrelated but it's more normal to write A' and A'' rather than A^{\prime} and A^{\prime\prime}  (you get the same output either way)

Your posted code does not produce the output shown it stops at ! Undefined control sequence. l.7 \captionof  (there is no reason to use \captionof in a table environment, but if you do use it you need to define it., similarly tabularx is not defined. nor \makecell. At this point i give up, please edit the question to fix the example.

I fixed it this time.

You could allow linebreaks after commas:

Although still rather ugly, are you sure a tabular layout is helping here at all?
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\caption{Transitions and Places of TEG in Fig.\ref{fig:TEG_5_Steps}}

\label{tab:table_MRT_2} 
\newcommand\cmma{\!,\linebreak[0]}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {
    @{}| c |
    r@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash} X  |
    r@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash} X |
    @{}}
  \hline
  \textbf{\makecell{ Variables}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Value}}   \\
  \hline
  $X^{1}$ &  $A'_{X^{1}} \equiv {}$&
  $\{P_{x^{1}_{[1]}}'\cmma  P_{x^{1}_{[2]}}''\cmma P_{x^{1}_{[3]}}'\}$ &
  $A''_{X^{1}} \equiv {}$&
  $\{P_{x_{[1]}}''\cmma  P_{x_{[2]}}'\cmma  P_{x_{[3]}}''\}$  \\
  \hline
  $X^{2}$ & $A'_{X^{2}} \equiv {}$&
  $\{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}'\cmma  P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}''\cmma P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}'\cmma P''_{x^{2}_{[4]}}\cmma P'_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\}$ &
  $A''_{X^{2}} \equiv {}$ &
  $\{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}''\cmma  P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}'\cmma P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}''\cmma P'_{x^{2}_{[4]}}\cmma P''_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\}$  \\
   \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}


Rather than trying to cram the formulas in a column, you might use table*.
I show two realizations of the table and I recommend the style in the latter.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{Transitions and Places of TEG in Fig.~\ref{fig:TEG_5_Steps}}
\label{tab:table_MRT_2} 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Variables} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Value}}   \\
\hline
$X^{1}$ &
  $A'_{X^{1}} \equiv \{P_{x^{1}_{[1]}}', P_{x^{1}_{[2]}}'',P_{x^{1}_{[3]}}'\}$ &
  $A''_{X^{1}} \equiv \{P_{x_{[1]}}'', P_{x_{[2]}}', P_{x_{[3]}}''\}$  \\
\hline
$X^{2}$ &
  $A'_{X^{2}} \equiv \{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}', P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}'',P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}',
                       P''_{x^{2}_{[4]}},P'_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\}$ &
  $A''_{X^{2}} \equiv \{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}'', P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}',P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}'',
                        P'_{x^{2}_{[4]}},P''_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\}$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{Transitions and Places of TEG in Fig.~\ref{fig:TEG_5_Steps}}
\label{tab:table_MRT_2-again} 

\begin{tabular}{@{}cll@{}}
\toprule
Variables & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value}   \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A'$} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$A''$} \\
\midrule
$X^{1}$ &
  $A'_{X^{1}} \equiv \{P_{x^{1}_{[1]}}', P_{x^{1}_{[2]}}'',P_{x^{1}_{[3]}}'\}$ &
  $A''_{X^{1}} \equiv \{P_{x_{[1]}}'', P_{x_{[2]}}', P_{x_{[3]}}''\}$  \\
\addlinespace
$X^{2}$ &
  $A'_{X^{2}} \equiv \{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}', P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}'',P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}',
                       P''_{x^{2}_{[4]}},P'_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\}$ &
  $A''_{X^{2}} \equiv \{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}'', P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}',P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}'',
                        P'_{x^{2}_{[4]}},P''_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\}$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\lipsum[8-20]

\end{document}


Alternatively, use just two columns:
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\caption{Transitions and Places of TEG in Fig.~\ref{fig:TEG_5_Steps}}
\label{tab:table_MRT_2} 

$\begin{array}{@{}cl@{}}
\toprule
\text{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\text{Value}} \\
\midrule
X^{1}
& A'_{X^{1}}  \equiv \{P_{x^{1}_{[1]}}', P_{x^{1}_{[2]}}'',P_{x^{1}_{[3]}}'\} \\
& A''_{X^{1}} \equiv \{P_{x_{[1]}}'', P_{x_{[2]}}', P_{x_{[3]}}''\} \\
\addlinespace
X^{2}
& A'_{X^{2}}  \equiv \{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}', P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}'',P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}',
                       P''_{x^{2}_{[4]}},P'_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\} \\
& A''_{X^{2}} \equiv \{P_{x^{2}_{[1]}}'', P_{x^{2}_{[2]}}',P_{x^{2}_{[3]}}'',
                        P'_{x^{2}_{[4]}},P''_{x^{2}_{[5]}}\} \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$

\end{table}

\lipsum[8-20]

\end{document}



Hi @egreg, thank you for your answer! In addition, from your second table, I would like to add three vertical lines to make it into two columns. I used $\begin{array}{|@{}c|l@{}|} , however the vertical line is broken (not connected). Do you have any idea how to add the vertical lines?

@NicholasTI Why ruining a table by adding vertical rules? A printed table is not a spreadsheet. You could do, instead, \begin{tabular}{@{}cl@{\qquad}l@{}}, so there's some more spacing between the columns.

I'd avoid using a tabular-like environment and, instead, use a four-row alignat* environment.

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtx}   % Times Roman text and math font
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat*' env.
\usepackage{lipsum}  % filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[ht]

\caption{Transitions and Places of TEG in Fig.~\ref{fig:TEG_5_Steps}}
\label{tab:table_MRT_2} 
\vspace*{-2ex}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\textnormal{Variables} &\qquad
&\textnormal{Values of $A'_{X^{i}}$ and $A''_{X^{i}}$,  $i=1,2$ } \\[1ex]
&X^{1} 
&&A'_{X^{1}} \equiv 
 \{P_{\!\!x^{1}_{[1]}}',  
   P_{\!\!x^{1}_{[2]}}'', 
   P_{\!\!x^{1}_{[3]}}'\}  \\[1ex]
&&&A''_{X^{1}} \equiv 
 \{P_{\!\!x_{[1]}}'',  
   P_{\!\!x_{[2]}}',  
   P_{\!\!x_{[3]}}''\}     \\[2ex]
&X^{2}
&&A'_{X^{2}} \equiv 
 \{P_{\!\!x^{2}_{[1]}}',  
   P_{\!\!x^{2}_{[2]}}'', 
   P_{\!\!x^{2}_{[3]}}', 
   P''_{\!\!x^{2}_{[4]}}, 
   P'_{\!\!x^{2}_{[5]}}\}  \\[1ex]
&&&A''_{X^{2}} \equiv 
 \{P_{\!\!x^{2}_{[1]}}'',  
   P_{\!\!x^{2}_{[2]}}', 
   P_{\!\!x^{2}_{[3]}}'', 
   P'_{\!\!x^{2}_{[4]}}, 
   P''_{\!\!x^{2}_{[5]}}\} 
\end{alignat*}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-7]

\end{document}

